# How to import an object from jupyter notebook to django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jupyter-notebook, django-extensions

I'm working on a web app which have the follow functionality:

1. User load an excel file
2. The web-app analysis the data
3. Shows results in graphics

I´m using django for backend and jupyter notebook to analysis the data and I have installed django-extensions for both to play nice. I've been able to upload the data and passing to the notebook but onces I have made all the analysis with it, I dont know how to export the result back to django for use it in the API.

The result object is a DataFrame like the image attached I have called `df_plot16`[image]

How can I do this? I have read that I have to put my notebook code in modules to export but I'm not sure this is the best way to do it. My project structure is like this and the data analysis code is inside the .ipynb

```
 - ClusterApp
 - MiApp
 - notebooks
     ClusterLogic.ipynb
 - static
 - templates
 - manage.py
```

Comment: frankly, I don't understand why to use jupyter for this. Why don't you put code in normal script.

Comment: because I pass cluster analysis(kmeans) before deliver the final object df_plot16

Comment: can't you do this in normal script ?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, Jupyter is excellent in my opinion for data analysis and I prefer to maintain my cluster code there (also it's a long document). By the way I'm quite new with django.

Comment: `Jupyter` is only tool to edit code. It is useful to test ideas but if you don't need to do any manual changes in code then you can put this code in normal file `script.py` and simply `import script`.

Comment: Ok, I understand that, but this means I have to copy and paste the entire code every time I'll change it. My goal is to avoid that connecting the note with django. With django-extensions I did that to import code to django, but how to export back? is any way to do that?

Comment: as I remeber `jupyter` has `export` to `.py` file - so you don't have to copy code manually. But I don't understand why you want to export code back - django normally doesn't change code but only data - so you have to only save results - ie. `CSV` or `pickle`

Comment: Maybe this helps to understand my process: 1. user upload data in excel (django) --> 2. data  goes to  notebook for analysis (Jupyter) --> results come back to show in front-end (django), sorry if this doesn't have much sense but I'm learning by myself and this is the way I'm doing it.

Comment: well, as for me Notebook is useless for this. 1. django gets uploaded file, 2. django runs code which analyzes data, 3. django displays results. As for me Notebook/Jupyter is only editor and it is useful to test some ideas (in interactive mode) but when code is correctly working then it should be used directly - without Notebook/Jupyter (and without interactive mode).

Comment: ok, understood, this works for me. Thanks!